# Why don't hyperlinks open in evince document viewer?

Tags: evince

I am using Evince document viewer as default in ubuntu 12.04.

How do I get a hyperlink to open when clicking on it?

Answer (score 3):

You encountered a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/964510) but there is a quick fix, I just did it and it worked, thanks to @maggotbrain by the way.
 He pointed me to [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/964510/comments/12), and the suggested solution worked. So I was able to fix this issue with google chrome by doing the following:

1. Open a terminal, type `gksudo nautilus` and hit enter,type your password and hit enter again, so now you are running nautilus with root privileges.
2. On nautilus go to `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/`
3. Open the `ubuntu-helpers` file and locate this lines inside:

   `# Allow exec of libexec applications in /usr/lib*`

   `/usr/lib*/{,**/}* Pixr,`
4. You will insert this block of text after those lines:

   ```
   # From https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apparmor/+bug/964510/comments/12
   # While the chromium and chrome sandboxes are setuid root, they only link
   # in limited libraries so glibc's secure execution should be enough to not
   # require the santized_helper (ie, LD_PRELOAD will only use standard system
   # paths (man ld.so)).
   /usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser-sandbox PUxr,
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox PUxr,
   /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome Pixr,
   /opt/google/chrome/chrome Pixr,
   /opt/google/chrome/lib*.so{,.*} m,
   ```

   but before this line:

   ```
   # Full access
   ```
5. Save the file, close nautilus.
6. Finally, type `sudo apparmor_parser -T -W -r
   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` on the terminal and hit enter, wait a few seconds until there is a line break and the cursor is awaiting for new input, this means the command went through with no problems :) hope it was helpful.

Comment: If by any chance it didn't work just open the file again, erase the same lines, save it and run `sudo apparmor_parser -T -W -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` again.

Comment: I went through all of this, as well as other stuff here, but haven't been successful yet, I still get the same error: https://askubuntu.com/questions/997511/how-to-open-a-link-in-a-pdf-with-the-error-unable-to-open-external-link-faile.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Is this still a bug in 20.04? I feel like this was probably fixed the last ten years and I am dealing with something else.

Answer (score 0):

- Open the  `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache` file.
- Search for the lines containing `x-scheme-handler/http=` and `x-scheme-handler/https=`.
- You should have either `firefox.desktop` or any other browser name followed by `.desktop` after the text in those lines.
- For example the line may read:

```
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the OP's question?

Comment: I tried reordering chrome, firefox and brave to brave, firefox and chrome (I prefer this order), but that didn't help.