# Can't open link in PDF

Tags: 16.04, pdf, evince, url

I'm using the default PDF viewer in Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9350. The link is a reference in a technical paper.

I get the error "Unable to open external link, Failed to execute child process "/opt/google/chrome/chrome" (Permission denied)"

I tried this solution without success: https://askubuntu.com/a/693663/657222

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem with firefox as default web browser , made chrome my default browser and it worked . try changing your default web browser .