# How to open a link in a PDF with the error: "Unable to open external link. Failed to execute child process “sh” (Permission denied)"?

Tags: permissions, pdf, evince, url

I have a similar problem to [this unanswered question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/925343/cant-open-link-in-pdf).

When I click on a link in a  PDF document using evince, I get the error: "Unable to open external link. Failed to execute child process “sh” (Permission denied)".

[image]

As a reference, the link is on p. 6 of this PDF: https://1drv.ms/b/s!ArWcVIN9MDpYlALaxYygOngeodbz. CTRL+F "culty parameter".

Note that you can just copy the link by right clicking it, and paste it into the browser, but it would be good to get the link to work by clicking on it directly.

When I click the link in Adobe Acrobat Reader on Windows 10, I get this prompt:

[image: PDF link permission prompt]

Clicking allow then opens the URL in the default browser. So I can confirm that this is an issue with Ubuntu.

Note that I can run Bash scripts from the command line, which is what I did to compose the PDF file from the TeX file, with a simple `./build.sh` command while `cd`ed to the directory of the file.

The issue also occurs in [this document](http://www.pubcom.com/508%20Links%20Test_2.pdf). Note that clicking links work fine with the PDF Viewer extension in the Brave browser.

Going through the steps in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317928/hyperlinks-clicked-in-evince-document-viewer-are-not-opening-any-ideas-on-how-t?rq=1), when I run evince and click a link, there is no output in Bash.

In Ubuntu 17.10, nothing still happens when you click help in the app dropdown menu.

Trying suggestions by @muru:

```
$ type -a sh
sh is /bin/sh
$ namei -lx /bin/sh
f: /bin/sh
Drwxr-xr-x root root /
drwxr-xr-x root root bin
lrwxrwxrwx root root sh -> dash
-rwxr-xr-x root root   dash
```

(While it probably doesn't matter, the documents are in my home directory, not an external HDD or above it.)

```
$ grep -i 'apparmor.*denied' /var/log/syslog | sort -uk12,12
Jan 19 12:11:44 james-Streacom kernel: [ 1243.518218] audit: type=1400 audit(1516324304.691:131): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="/usr/bin/evince//sanitized_helper" pid=4894 comm="WebKitWebProces" family="netlink" sock_type="raw" protocol=0 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
Jan 19 11:01:55 james-Streacom kernel: [ 3443.867198] audit: type=1400 audit(1516320115.513:125): apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/bin/dash" pid=7738 comm="evince" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 19 12:59:09 james-Streacom kernel: [ 4088.301201] audit: type=1400 audit(1516327149.446:146): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_mmap" profile="snap.akasha.akasha" name="/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu-font-family/Ubuntu-R.ttf" pid=6997 comm="akasha" requested_mask="m" denied_mask="m" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 19 10:47:22 james-Streacom kernel: [ 2571.053151] audit: type=1400 audit(1516319242.706:123): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/bin/evince" name="/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/mimeinfo.cache" pid=7011 comm="evince" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
Jan 19 00:07:17 james-Streacom kernel: [52772.610086] audit: type=1400 audit(1516280837.487:52060): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.akasha.akasha" name="/sys/bus/usb/devices/" pid=31923 comm="geth" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
```

Comment: It's a long output, I'll make a Gist file; it has lots of messages with `apparmor="DENIED"`. Actually it's so long that it overran the messages that Bash can display, so I'll have to log it to a file.

Comment: I think I have found the problem. This is one line: `apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.akasha.akasha" name="/sys/bus/usb/devices/" pid=31923 comm="geth" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0`. The akasha application seems to be blocking it, even though it's not running. https://gist.github.com/jamesray1/f05fd70dbe20e8d74102f1874676ca7d. I'll report an issue with the developers. However, I remember getting this error before I installed Akasha, which I only installed just yesterday night.

Comment: I didn't expect so much output, sorry about that. Try: `grep -i 'apparmor.*denied' /var/log/syslog | sort -uk12,12`. That should show you the correct source of the problem: AppArmor denying gedit from opening anything outside a specific whitelist.

Comment: Yes it might be Akasha or geth, or something in the mimeinfo.cache, or sanitized_helper. https://gist.github.com/jamesray1/fd8c68faebf84f1bb6d493d0a9c5f379. Akasha/Geth is the earliest one so I guess it is that. I tried to turn off Geth and IPFS and close Akasha, but I still got the error.

Comment: The Akasha thing is a red herring. It's the sanitized helper. Check `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince` - you'll see evince is only allowed to open some specific applications. Now how you want to solve this is up to you - you could add a command to that whitelist, or disable AppArmor for evince (like it's disabled for Firefox, IIRC).

Comment: I read usr.bin.evince but I'm not sure what command to add, or how to disable AppArmor for evince. I'll try `/usr/bin/brave ixr,`.

Comment: I'm trying to edit `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.bin.evince`. I tried `sudo gedit`, but that didn't open, so I used  `GDK_BACKEND=wayland gedit`, which opened gedit, but I couldn't edit and save the file. https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5243354.html. I'll try changing the modes for the file. I may also try the other option.

Comment: That would probably be https://askubuntu.com/q/961967/158442. Use `sudo nano` or `sudo vim` if you are comfortable with those.

Comment: As per the linked post I used `xhost si:localuser:root`, `su -`, `gedit`, added `/usr/bin/brave ixr,`, saved the file and tried to open a link again, but that didn't work. Adding `/bin/sh ixr,` didn't work, either.

Comment: I disabled AppArmor as per http://www.techytalk.info/disable-and-remove-apparmor-on-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions/ (without purging it), but that didn't work.

Comment: I'll file a bug at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/.

Comment: I changed the default browser to Chrome, and it worked! Also, when Firefox was set to the default browser, it worked! So it must be a bug with the Brave browser, which I'll file.

Comment: Excellent! You can post that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

If the Brave browser is set to the default browser, this error occurs, but it doesn't occur if Firefox or Chrome are set to default. I have posted an issue [here](https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/issues/12715).