# clicking on hyperlinks in evince crashes google chrome ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, google-chrome, evince

I've read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254212/why-dont-hyperlinks-open-in-evince-document-viewer?rq=1) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317928/hyperlinks-clicked-in-evince-document-viewer-are-not-opening-any-ideas-on-how-t) questions and tried to do what is supposed there (editing ubuntu-helpers, restarting apparmor) but it seems that in ubuntu 15.04 ubuntu-helpers already contains the lines needed and I still get message "application crashed" (or whatever it looks in English) about Google Chrome when I first click on hyperlink in pdf in Evince (all the next clicks just do nothing).

I'm really frustrated and don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I suddenly discovered that hyperlinks started working. Either something I've done before finally worked or there was some update in evince, I don't know. Big relief, anyway.