# Evince can open hyperlinks in Firefox, so why not in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, pdf, evince

Before posting this question I investigated [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254212/why-dont-hyperlinks-open-in-evince-document-viewer) and found it already implemented in my 14.04.  Also investigated [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317928/hyperlinks-clicked-in-evince-document-viewer-are-not-opening-any-ideas-on-how-t?lq=1) which references the above linked question.  Handlers for both google-chrome.desktop and firefox.desktop are in place in my system.

A description follows below.  Can anyone please suggest a way to track down and solve this problem?

**The problem statement:**

The system is Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit, freshly installed July 10, 2015, including LibreOffice Writer 4.2.8.2.  The default document reader is Evince 3.10.3.

A PDF document containing internet hyperlinks is opened in Evince.  If the default browser is Firefox, a click on any hyperlink properly opens a page in Firefox.  But if the default browser is Chrome a hyperlink click does nothing, even if Chrome is already launched.

**Here's a demonstration.**

Create a document in LiberOffice Writer that contains internet hyperlinks.  While the document is open in Writer, **ctrl+click** on a link opens the page in the default browser, either Chrome or Firefox.

Now export the document to PDF and close Writer.

Double-click on PDF file name; it opens it in Evince.  If Firefox is the default browser a clicked link opens properly.  If Chrome is the default browser the cursor changes to a link pointer on hovering over the link, but a click does nothing.

NOTE:  A PDF can also be opened for print preview in Gnome Document Viewer.  The document presents nicely in this viewer and the cursor changes to a link pointer when hovering over a link, but clicked links do nothing regardless of which browser is default.

**Now try to gain some clues.**

Close Evince and re-launch it from a terminal.  Then File > Open the PDF document.  If Firefox is the default browser a clicked link opens properly and the following presents in terminal:

When page load begins:  `(process:3226): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed`

When page load completes:  `Vector smash protection is enabled.`

Close Firefox and change default browser to Chrome.  The PDF is still open in Evince.  A link click does nothing and nothing presents in terminal.

Change default browsers between Chrome and Firefox a few times leaving PDF open in Evince.  In every case with default Firefox a clicked link opens properly with the same reports in terminal, but no action occurs with default Chrome.

Comment: Not a solution but an idea. You can right click and Copy Link Address, then open Chrome and paste and go