# Weblink redirection to site from pdf

Tags: permissions, google-chrome, pdf, evince

While opening a PDF in evince and click any web link on that PDF it is not redirecting to the site on UBUNTU 12.04. My default browser is google chrome. I have updated it recently. In terminal a error like this is shown while trying to open the Web link in PDF.

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 51: /opt/google/chrome/chrome: Success
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable: line 51: /opt/google/chrome/chrome: Permission denied.
```

Earlier I was able to open links in chrome. Why this is happening?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/254212/why-dont-hyperlinks-open-in-evince-document-viewer. By following this answer I was able to open links on the PDF through Mozilla Firefox it worked for me.