# Hyperlinks in evince do not open

Tags: gnome, pdf, evince, wayland

I cannot open links in evince (I'm using chromium).

Starting it from terminal, the error message I get when clicking a link is

`error while loading shared libraries: libwayland-egl.so.1: failed to map segment from shared object`

I'm using Gnome on Xorg, but the same happens on unity on Wayland. Ubuntu is 18.04.01 LTS and Gnome version 3.28.2.

Edit: The mentioned [other thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254212/why-dont-hyperlinks-open-in-evince-document-viewer) does not answer my question. The bug discussed there has already been fixed and affected an old version of Ubuntu. As should be clear from the error message, there is a problem with wayland, something that wasn't even in the distro 6 years ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why don't hyperlinks open in evince document viewer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254212/why-dont-hyperlinks-open-in-evince-document-viewer)

Comment: Thanks, @S_Flash, but unfortunately the stated solution did not help me. Plus it is on a 6 year older Ubuntu & the OP hasn't provided any information that might help to determine the problem.